# MFC app "Not Responding", although computation is already in separate thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

I didn't find sufficient answer for this, any suggestion is welcome..
I have a simple MFC single-document app, upon opening file a lengthy computation takes place in separate thread:

```
BOOL CrhMonkeyDoc::OnOpenDocument(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
    if (!CDocument::OnOpenDocument(lpszPathName))
        return FALSE;

    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();

    // Start working thread to process the file
    m_rhFile.StartParseFile(lpszPathName);

    //periodically check progress and update 
    int progress, lines;
    while ((progress = m_rhFile.GetProgress()) < 1000) {
        lines = m_rhFile.GetNumLines();

        CString strProgress;
        strProgress.Format(_T("%d lines, %d percent complete"), lines, progress);
        pMainFrame->SetStatusBarText(strProgress);

        Sleep(1000);
    }

    UpdateAllViews(NULL);
}
```

The thread is started like this:

```
UINT ParseFileThread(LPVOID Param)
{
    RhFile* rhFile = (RhFile*)Param;
    rhFile->ParseFile();
    return TRUE;
}
int RhFile::StartParseFile(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
    m_file.open(lpszPathName);
    AfxBeginThread(ParseFileThread, this);
    return 0;
}
```

Initially it does work updating the status bar periodically, but after 10-15 seconds the updates stop and "Not Responding" appears in app title.
I have tried to start the thread at lower priority, and also added periodic SwitchToThread() (always returning 0), and Sleep(50) inside ParseFile(), but it doesn't help.

I guess I am doing something wrong, but can't figure out what

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: The while loop in `CrhMonkeyDoc::OnOpenDocument` that checks the progress blocks the main thread.  Change your thread proc to post a custom message back to your main window to indicate it's progress.  Process this custom message in your main window proc.

Comment: You should post progress messages from a worker thread and listen to them as part of message loop in main thread. Or set up a timer in main thread and check for progress periodically.

Comment: Thanks Richard - I understand the Sleep(1000) is not the right thing to do..

Comment: It's not just the `Sleep`, any loop on the main thread will stop the message pump and after a few seconds give _"application not responding"_.

Comment: The main issue is that you are not processing messages in your while loop. When Windows notices that after some timeout, it will put the dreaded "Not Responding" into your title bar. Another way to fix that, which wasn't mentioned yet is to [use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` to get woken up when messages arrive and then process them like a regular message loop does](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060126-00/?p=32513). Beware reentrancy issues though.